# What is the best way of sharing Correlation Id Azure Function V2

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions, correlation

I have a durable function app which has been designed as

Event Grid Trigger Starter Function --> Orchestrator Function --> Activity Functions

Within those activity functions, there might have HttpClient calls for third parties. Therefore, adding correlation id into those request headers is also essential.

I tried to implement HTTP message delegate handler `CorrelationIdHandler : DelegatingHandler` with injecting dependency with scoped lifetime for adding X-Correlation-ID header in each request. but it was unsuccessful to resolve dependency with scoped lifetime in delegate handler class.

since I'm getting subsequent events, it is really important to maintain scoped lifetime as well.

Please suggest me a good way of sharing correlation Id across orchestrator function and activity functions and delegate handlers